# Deleting a file in sublime text 3 using the python command line

Tags: python, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I'm using sublime text 3 and I wanted to find a way to delete a file/folder using just the command line for easier development/ faster development.

I've installed advance_new_file so that I can easily create files and folders using just the shortcut key `ctrl` + `alt` + `n`. It's pretty smooth. But now I cannot find a way to delete files.

There is a command line tool in ST3 and pressing `ctrl`+ ` will open the command line. Is there a shortcut on deleting files without having me use the mouse?

Comment: `rm filename`, `rm -rf foldername`? :)

Comment: that's a terminal thing.. T_T

Answer (score 2):

It opens the `Python Interpreter`. To delete the file, you have to import `os` or `subprocess` module and invoke `rm` command.

If you are using **Linux**, you are in luck. Install Guake: http://guake.org/.

These two keystrokes: **F12 and Alt+Tab** will allow you to do your tasks without mouse quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to an open shell prompt with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> is probably your fastest bet, but if you have lots of open windows or just want to do everything from within sublime, there are a couple of options.

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>`</kbd> opens the built-in version of Python, in ST3 this is 3.3. From there, you can run `import os`, then use [`os.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove) to delete a file and [`os.rmdir()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir) to delete an empty directory. To delete a directory with contents, first `import shutil` then use [`shutil.rmtree()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.rmtree). Other `shutil` methods like [`shutil.copy()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy) (or [`shutil.copy2()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy2), for preserving metadata), [`shutil.move()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move), and [`shutil.copytree()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copytree) are also useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ["shell command" package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Shell%20Command).To install this, firstly follow the instruction to install the package control.

(win)/(command)+shift+p to bring out the command tools and find this Package Control -> Install Package and find "shell command".

You should be able to execute shell command on the fly with the shortcut key. Refer the page for more information.